# Unable to open HAXM device: ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: android-emulator, intel-haxm

I am getting intel haxm error while running emulator. It was working 1 month back but stopped a while back. I tried a temporary solution to disable driver reinforcement which starts the emulator but it doesn't work in big app projects and whole app/emulator starts crashing. I have to disable driver reinforcement with each reboot to make it work. Not GOOD idea :/

Secondly, few guys said to enable vt in bios and I did that too but again same issue. Any suggestions?

**Error and PC Info is listed below**
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem in windows 10, which was solved by [disabling Hyper-v](https://ugetfix.com/ask/how-to-disable-hyper-v-in-windows-10/) and reinstalling HAXM via SDK Manager>SDK Tools>Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator

Comment: There is no option in Windows 7

Comment: Thanks! I ran into this problem after installing Visual Studio Emulator for Android. Your solution worked for me.